# What algorithm will convert a regex into a tree of predictable size?

Tags: graphs, trees, regular-expressions

How do we quantify the size of a regular expression?

A problem in computer science which sometimes arises is converting a regular expression into a tree.

What rules can we use to ensure that the tree will have a predictable number of nodes?

---

I know what to do for simple character classes such as `[0-9]` and `[A-Z]`.

However, I do not know how to handle negative look behinds and all sorts of other fancy things.

Given that there are many different flavors of regex, please assume that we the flavor of regular expressions used in the Java SE 19 standard.

---

## Example regex with an associated tree of three nodes `a|b`

[image: TREE OF THE REGEX "A|B". SHOWS ONE ROOT NODE WITH TWO CHILDREN. THREE NODES IN TOTAL ARE IN THE TREE]

For regex $\mathtt{a|b}$ the associated tree has $3$ nodes.

---

## Example regex with an associated tree of $27$ nodes

[image: A TREE OF THE REGEX CHARACTER CLASS [A-Z] letters THE TREE CONTAINS 27 NODES]

For the character class $\mathtt{[A-Z]}$ the size of the associated tree is $27$

---

In general, for a regular expression character class containing $n$ characters, the number of nodes in the tree associated with the character class is $n + 1$.

> - There are $n$ children of the root node
> - The root node represents logical-disjuction and/or the union of sets. In regular expressions logical-disjuction is usually written as `|` or `or`.

---

An example I would like to calculate the number of nodes in a regex and use algorithms from the field of optimization to minimize the number of nodes in the tree by modifying the tree.

RFC 5322

Maybe you’re wondering why there’s no “official” fool-proof regex to match email addresses. Well, there is an official definition, but it’s hardly fool-proof.

The official standard is known as RFC 5322. It describes the syntax that valid email addresses must adhere to. You can (but you shouldn’t—read on) implement it with the following regular expression. RFC 5322 leaves the domain name part open to implementation-specific choices that won’t work on the Internet today. The regex implements the “preferred” syntax from RFC 1035 which is one of the recommendations in RFC 5322:

The following is a commonly used regular expression to match email addresses.

```
\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+)*
 |  "(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]
      |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")
@ (?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
  |  \[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
       (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:
          (?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]
          |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)
     \])\z
```

How would we convert that regex into a tree?

Comment: How would a regex with a star, such as a*, be a tree of bounded height?

Comment: 1) Please ask only one  question per post.  This seems to ask two separate questions: How do you define the size of a regular expression?  How do you convert a regex to a tree?  2) How do you choose an ice cream flavor?  There are many possible ways to define the size of a regular expression.  So we can't tell you how to define the size of a regular expression.  3) I don't know what you mean by convert a regex to a tree.  Please specify precisely what relationship you want the two to have.  If you don't know what you're trying to achieve, it's premature to ask how to do that conversion.